# Handle selection via has_many in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, messaging

I’m new to Rails development and I’m trying to build a simple messenger app with basic functionality.
The app has three models: `User`, `Message`, and `Room`. There is a relation between rooms and users:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
  has_many :users, through: :messages
end
```

Also, the Message model looks like this:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room
end
```

The question is: how do I select all messages that belong to all the rooms my `current_user` is member of with ActiveRecord?

For example, if my user is in room 1 with messages 1, 2, 3 and in room 2 with messages 4, 5, 6, but he is only the author of messages 1 and 4, I need to select all 6 messages.

I could only achieve this through a for-loop which is the ugliest and most inefficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your `User` model these three associations

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
  has_many :rooms, through: :messages
  has_many :all_messages, through: :rooms, class_name: 'Message', source: :messages
end
```

And in your code you can use following:

```rb
current_user.all_messages
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, it worked! The only thing I had to add to achieve the desired outcome, was “current_user.all_messages.distinct”, otherwise it returned three times the list of messages. Not sure why, will have to buff my SQL expertise to figure it out